# FontAwesome Icons displays as white on iPad instead of Black as on other platforms making them almost invisible

Tags: html, ipad, font-awesome

I use [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) icons in my web application. The application is not a website but installed on a users computer with the UI accessed via web-browser. The FontAwesome css sheets are installed locally as part of the application.

Everything seemed to be working fine

e.g

[image]

Html code for the icons as follows

```
    <button value="Rename Files" name="renamefiles" title="Rename Files" type="submit" form="form_id" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" style="background:transparent" class="btn">
        <i class="fa-light fa-folders fa-2xl">
        </i>
    </button>
```

However, although it works fine on PC and my Android based phone **on my iPad the icons are white instead of black and almost invisible** I tested with both Safari and Firefox, and they both had the same problem.

What could be the problem?

Comment: could this be because of the dark theme in your ipad?  Check the link below and try changing dark and light theme

https://fontawesome.com/v6/icons/folders?f=classic&s=light

Comment: please check if any content blockers / ad blockers active on your iPad and are mistakenly blocking fontawesome from loading. Try disabling them / whitelisting your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user @SandeepM says, very likely the reason is because your ipad is using a dark theme.

A simple way to fix that would be to set colors explicitly in your code. For example:

```
i.fa-light,
i.fa-light:before,
i.fa-light:after{
   color:black;
}
```

should change them to `black`.

Comment: so does FontAwesome automtically adjust based on OS Dark/Light Mode ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor FontAwesome uses the font `color` of the parent, which inherits up the chain until the body. If you're seeing a difference based upon *DEVICE*, that means one of two things is happening. #1: One of his parents is changing font colors based upon the device, which likely means it's affected by Dark Mode of the device, or #2: Your ipad is an older device and doesn't have a browser compatible with CSS variables, and somehow FA's color's CSS variables are affected, or #3: You have a nasty `@media query` somewhere that's interfering specifically at the screen resolution of iPad.

Comment: @PaulTaylor As the color is changing from "Black" to "White" specifically on one device, my first assumption would be Dark Mode on that device, but truthfully, any of the three are possibilities...... That said, the solution I posted of hard-coding the color would most likely solve the issue *no matter which of the three* was the original cause, so.... :)

Comment: The key point here is that FA's icons are literally a cool-looking `font-family`, so the problem we're really trying to debug is, **"Why is my text changing color?"**

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the icon is always black, add the `style="color: black;"` attribute to the `<i>` tag (the icon).

```html
<button value="Rename Files" name="renamefiles" title="Rename Files" type="submit" form="form_id" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" style="background:transparent" class="btn">
    <i class="fa-light fa-folders fa-2xl" style="color: black;">
    </i>
</button>
```